# What's the windows 10 first-time dialog?

Tags: windows-10

When you start up a Windows 10 computer for the first time ever (as in, you literally just bought it), there is dialog, which says something along the lines of "Hi." [cuts to next screen] and then it says something there. Does anyone know/remember the rest of the dialog? Alternatively the update dialog: "We've updated your PC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog can be found on [this](https://youtu.be/5p2lHKqQ6cc?t=442) YouTube video. It is:

> - Hi
> - We're setting things up for you
> - This won't take long (smaller subtext: Setting up your apps)
> - Let's start

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that happen on a new computer when you first turn it on.

First, the Windows Out-Of-Box-Experience (OOBE) runs which takes the new owner through the initial configuration of Windows like connecting to WiFi and setting up a new user account. This process is actually broken down in to two sub processes - Computer OOBE and User OOBE.

Second, the new user is logged in and the “First sign-in animation” is run while the new user profile is setup. This is what you are referring to. All new users see this the first time they login and typically after a major upgrade to Windows. The message has evolved over the years through different versions of Windows.

Both items can be disabled in various ways. Usually via what is called an “unattend” file during OS deployment or via group policy.